# Is the endomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ induced by multiplication by $p^{n}$ surjective?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number. Is it true that $p^{n}\mathbb{Z}_{p}\cong\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ as additive groups for any natural number $n$ and if so, why? Here, $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ denotes the ring of $p$-adic integers.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean $\,\Bbb Z_p\;$ = the $\;p$-adic integers or the integers modulo $\;p\;$ ? I guess it must be the former. otherwise...

Comment: Yes, I meant the ring of $p$-adic integers.

Comment: @DonAntonio With "ring of $p$-adic integers" one commonly means the $p$-adic completion of the integers. This ring is the localization of the integers at $p$.

Comment: @egreg, the OP already made it clear it is the ring of $\;p$-adic integers and he even edited his question in this respect. What do you mean "this ring" is the localization of the integers at $\,p\,$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio I've never seen the ring of $p$-adic integer denoted like this.

Comment: I think the notation is correct, while the localization is usually denoted $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$.

Comment: @egreg I've never seen the ring of $p$-adic integers denoted otherwise! How else do you write it?

Comment: @Cocopuffs At least with a hat. But that's unimportant.

Comment: @egreg, it is very, very common: it appears so in Dummint & Foote, sec. 7.6, page 269, ex. 11 , also here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number with some explanation about other notations, also in sec. 1.10 in Lang's "Algebra". But I really don't like this notation as it may be confusing. OTOH, the completion of the integers wrt $\,p\,$ I've seen as $\,\Bbb Z_{(p)}\;$

Comment: The title and the body ask different questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The multiplication by $p^n$ is injective - after all, $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is an integral domain - and so it gives an isomorphism $$\mathbb{Z}_p \cong p^n \mathbb{Z}_p$$ to its image. That doesn't make it surjective as an endomorphism, though, and it isn't, because $p^n$ isn't invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clear that $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ denotes the ring of $p$-adic integers. I take it that you assumed it to be the ring of integers modulo $p$?

Comment: @user68418 I am working with that ring.

Comment: I can't see why the injectivity of the multiplication should imply surjectivity, unless the ring is finite.

Comment: @user68418: Not only $\Bbb Z_p$ isn't finite, it isn't countable either.

Comment: @user68418 That's the point - it isn't surjective!

Comment: @Cocopuffs  Could you please explain how the isomorphism follows from the injectivity of the multiplication? Many thanks.

Comment: @user68418 Tomasz has it. $p^n : \mathbb{Z}_p \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p$ isn't surjective, but $p^n : \mathbb{Z}_p \rightarrow p^n \mathbb{Z}_p$ is surjective by definition of $p^n \mathbb{Z}_p$!

Comment: @tomasz I see it now! Just ignore my previous comments. Many thanks guys...

Comment: @tomasz: But there isn't any injective ring homomorphism under consideration here. The injective map considered here is only an endomorphism of the additive group. In fact, I think the part "as an endomorphism" leads to possible confusion and should be followed by "of Abelian groups"; the presence of this phrase is only to stress the "endo" part, and the "morphism" part is just there because one can not reasonably omit it.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: Touché. Well, the same is true for groups, so it's okay.

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate a little, note elements $\mathbb{Z}_p$ are sequences $(a_0,a_1,...,a_n,...)$ with $a_i\equiv a_j\mod (p^i)$ whenever $i<j$. Denote by $p(n)$ the greatest number such that $p^{p(n)}|n$ ($+\infty$ if $n=0$). Now from the relation we see $p(a_j)=p(a_i)$ if $a_i\ne 0$. So if $a,b\ne 0\in \mathbb{Z}_p$, $p(a_i)$ and $p(b_i)$ will be finite and stationary for sufficiently large $i$, so will it be for $ab$, which proves that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is an integral domain.

Answer (score 1):

No (for the question in title) and yes (for the question in the body).

There is a ring morphsism $\newcommand\Z{\Bbb Z}\Z_p\to \Z/p\Z$, because of the inverse limit construction that defines the $p$-adic integers (there are similarly morphisms to any $\Z/p^k\Z$). Under this morphism multiplication by $p^n$ transforms into multiplication by $0^n$ and since that is not surjective in $\Z/p\Z$ (unless $n=0$ of course) it follows that multiplication by $p^n$ cannot be surjective in $\Z_p$.

However multiplication by any nonzero element, such as $p^n$, in the integral domain $\Z_p$ is injective and thus induces an isomorphism of Abelian groups from $\Z_p$ to the image of the multiplication (a principal ideal of $\Z_p$), in particular here $\Z_p\cong p^n\Z_p$ as Abelian groups (or as $\Z_p$-modules if you like, but not as rings since $p^n\Z_p$ is not a (unitary) ring at all).